# jQuery Galleria Thumbnail not displaying

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I had set up Galleria Plugin successfully. But the problem is that the thumbnails for each picture is not generating. My code is below

```
<div id="galleria">
        <img title="Image title" src="images/1.jpg">
        <img title="Image title" src="images/2.jpg">
        <img title="Image title" src="images/3.jpg">
        <img title="Image title" src="images/4.jpg">
        <img title="Image title" src="images/5.jpg">
        <img title="Image title" src="images/6.jpg">
        <img title="Image title" src="images/7.jpg">
        <img title="Image title" src="images/8.jpg">
        <img title="Image title" src="images/9.jpg">
        <img title="Image title" src="images/10.jpg">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
     Galleria.loadTheme('js/galleria.classic.js');
     $('#galleria').galleria();
</script>
```

What can I try next?

Comment: A live example would be more than appreciated in this instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i changed the display:none for the slideshow window to visibility:hidden and its working!. thanks for all who answered

Answer (score 0):

Never used the script, but what i advise is:

- check your jQuery framework file path
- check your image paths, try using
  exact paths not relative
- set `script` tag with
  `type="text/javascript"` attribute

Good luck